# how to prevent on scroll event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When scrolling page How to prevent on scroll event from triggering?

```
$('.child, .preschool, .first-year, ').on('keyup keydown change', function(e) {
showResults();})
```

Comment: Remove the scroll event from your code

Comment: Means you don't want the scroll to work but the keyup, keydown and change needs to work instead. Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: Explain in detail?

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770025/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily